# google-auth-library v.1.0 how to use just for identity?

Tags: node.js, identity, google-authentication

I,ve been using google-auth-library@0.10.0 nodejs just for verifying user identity in my api services, now it changed to 1.0 and everything is broken.

I previously used example from here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

now I cannot figure out how to verify identity using the new library. 
Examples here: https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs
explains how to get access to google apis, I just need to verify identity.
this is my code:

```
 const GoogleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
    const auth = new GoogleAuth.GoogleAuth();
    const google = require('googleapis');
    const authData = {
      'googleAuth': {
        'clientID': 'xxxxxxxxxxx-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'clientSecret': 'sssssssssssssssssssssssss',
        'callbackURL': 'http://localhost:121212/auth/'
      }
    };
const CLIENT_ID = authData.googleAuth.clientID;
    function verifyToken(token) {
      let tokenPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        client.verifyIdToken(
          token,
          CLIENT_ID,
          // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
          //[CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3],
          function(e, login) {
            if (e) {
              return reject(e);
            } else {
              var payload = login.getPayload();
              var userid = payload['sub'];
              //console.log(payload, userid, e, login);
              return resolve(login);
              // If request specified a G Suite domain:
              //var domain = payload['hd'];
            }

          });
      });

      return tokenPromise;

    };
```

it was working fine, just to get googleUserId.

now I've this error:

Error: This method accepts an options object as the first parameter, which includes the idToken, audience, and maxExpiry.

I understand I'm not passing properly parameters and maybe its not the method to use..but how can I know which method and how it accepts parameters??? I cannot find any documentation about google-auth-library@1.0...some one is using it in production??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verifyIdToken changed. Here's a working example.

```
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library';
const client = new OAuth2Client(
  'xxxxxxxxxxx-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.apps.googleusercontent.com,
  'sssssssssssssssssssssssss',
  'http://localhost:121212/auth/',
);
client.verifyIdToken({
  idToken: TOKEN,
  audience: CLIENT_ID_1 // If you have multiple [CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, ...]
}, (err, login) => {
  console.log(login);
});
```

Just tested this recently.

Google needs to update their documentation.

Please note that you can specify a maxAge to the verify id token options as well.

Here's the interface copied from the source code

```
export interface VerifyIdTokenOptions {
  idToken: string;
  audience: string|string[];
  maxExpiry?: number;
}
```

As you can see the `idToken` and `audience` are required, the `maxExpiry` is optional.

Source can be found [here](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/64fb34d1855a799d74c385517d6403d3c6e05a16/src/auth/oauth2client.ts#L213)

Comment: In this case audience is the value in "Client ID" in the credentials OAuth 2.0 client IDs.